# Find value % within a range

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I would like to find out what % a particular value is as a function of a "min" and "max" for that range.

e.g.
Min = 15
Max = 30

If Value = 15 then 0%
If value = 30 then 100%

If value = 7.5 then -50%
If value = 60 then 200%

Can't work out how to achieve this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems simple: `((value - min) * 100) / (max - min)`.

Comment: Sorry, the range can change and the value needs to be within the range.
So If the range is e.g. 20-40 then 30 would be 50%, 20 would be 0% and 40 would be 100%.
If the range was 20-60 then 30 would be much closer to 0%.

i.e. It's not a % of the min value, its the % between the two values.

Comment: Sorry - updated.